# Call image processing function before image upload in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my demo I'm using the https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads package for image uploading and its working like a charm. Now I want to call my image processing function before the file is uploaded.

Once my image processing function is done, I want to start uploading the image to my local (that is already working by meteor-uploads package).

How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I would switch over to using [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS). They have image manipulation ( imagemagick, graphicsmagick) abilities for file file uploads. So when you define your collection using CollectionFS use:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [
   new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbs", { transformWrite: createThumb }),
   new FS.Store.FileSystem("images"),
  ],
 filter: {
   allow: {
     contentTypes: ['image/*'] //allow only images in this FS.Collection
   }
 }
});

var createThumb = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
  // Transform the image into a 10x10px thumbnail
  gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('10', '10').stream().pipe(writeStream);
};
```

Notice that the createThumb is using `graphicsmagick` in the function `createThumb` (`gm`) to resize the image for you before inserting it into the collection `images` under the specific store `thumbs`.

Comment: ok thanks, is it possible to apply image watermarking on a image stored in my folder using this meteor-uploads?

Comment: @Meteor yeah you could use the `gm` composite function http://www.graphicsmagick.org/composite.html.

Comment: yeah, that's great. Is there any methods that can apply Image Watermarking before uploading image using this https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads ?

Comment: @Meteor, it doesn't seem like `meteor-uploads` have any image manipulation functionalitly. What feature of `meter-uploads` do you want that you can't achieve in `collectionFS` or do you just not want to refactor your code?

Comment: actually i want to apply image watermarking when uploading image to my local folder using http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs.